AngularJs, select control, cannot pass the selected value to javascript using ng-Model
In javascript
$scope.testNames = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']; 
$scope.selTestName = $scope.testNames[0];
$scope.test = function(){
    $log.debug('selTestName=' + $scope.selTestName);
}

In jsp
<td colspan="3" class="input-medium">
        <select class="span2" ng-model="selTestName" style="font-family: verdana;"
            ng-options="testName for testName in testNames">
    </select></td>
    {{selTestName}}
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-info" ng-click="test()">Test selTestName</button>                    
    </td>

When my selected value change, the interpolaton {{selTestName}} change accordingly, but whatever I selected and press Test button, in javascript side, the $scope.selTestName keep unchange, why?
How can I make the $scope.setTestName change according to my selected value? I already set ng-Model = "selTestName".
My angularjs version is 1.2.26

Copying your code, it seems to work correctly for me... ‍♂️ The only thing I changed was $log.debug, to a console.log

the code is from a large application, don't know how to copy  just a runnable segment about the problematic code. :(


"If you use ng-model, you have to have a dot in there." Make your
model point to an object.property and you'll be good to go."

Finally I find the answer here:
Ng-model does not update controller value
The problem is here
ng-model="selTestName" 

ng-model need to use object.property.
Like the following:
$scope.testNames = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']; 
$scope.selTestName = {tableName:$scope.testNames[0]};

jsp/html:
<select class="span2" ng-model="selTestName.tableName" style="font-family: verdana;"
            ng-options="testName for testName in testNames">
    </select></td>

And this solves my problem successfully.
Anyway, there is another question now, as I found the following still works also even ng-model is not using dot.notation.
https://jsfiddle.net/ejghzyo3/7/
Anyway, this is already another new question, maybe I create a new question on this.
